# SSH behind proxy ?

Tags: ssh, security, proxy, ssh-tunnel

What is the best way to SSH to my sever behind company proxy , it seems that 22 port is not opened by default , is there any simple way to do that rather than to install corkscrew ??

When I do :

```
✗ ssh -i ~/.ec2/mykey.pem ubuntu@XX.XX.XXX.XXX
ssh: connect to host XX.XX.XXX.XXX port 22: Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple way is to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf` on the server (`XX.XX.XXX.XXX`) to listen on some port you can access through the proxy. For example port 80 is not usually blocked. Port 443 is another good candidate. If you don't have root access to the server, you might persuade whoever has to do it for you. `sshd` must be restarted after changing the file for the effect to take place.

A different, simple, approach is to ask whoever administers the proxy to let you connect through it on port 22.

Comment: Of course, you'll also need to tell the SSH client to connect to that port. e.g. via `ssh -p 2222 hostname` or (better, because the option also works with `scp` etc.) `ssh -o Port=2222 hostname`.  And port 80 can be hooked up with e.g. transparent HTTP proxies for caching or filtering, so that may not work very well... you would need to find a port that passes the connection through unmolested.

Comment: Also, what zigg said.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't aware of corkscrew, but that seems like your best bet, if you can issue CONNECT requests through an HTTP proxy.  Either that, or use the `ProxyCommand` directive with some other command that can make the connection for you.

You really should be talking to your network administrator about your need to use SSH though.