# Can't connect via ssh from work

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop

I have home station with debian on it. Today while being at office i had to make some changes in debian config, and i had to do it very urgent. I thought there will be no problem, because home station has static ip and ssh on, but after i've downloaded PuTTY 0.63 on my windows workstation i was unable to connect with "connection timed out" error.
Here, at my office all machines are behind proxy, but i need some of the blocked sites so admins just added me to exception list and i don't use proxy anymore. Browsing internet pages works fine.
SSH daemon on my home machine works. I can connect it via android ssh client from my phone(that's how i've managed to do the work).

RDP on virtual windows machine which is also at my home has the same issue(can't connect from work, but everything works fine with mobile RDP client)

What can be the issue of this? Probably corporate firewall? May be i can find out what ports are free and use them for outcoming connection?

Comment: There are quite a few questions here on working with SSH through a proxy. It's most probably a corporate firewall thing. Ask your admins, or use a port for SSH that's free. See also: http://superuser.com/questions/537576/connecting-to-ssh-from-behind-an-http-proxy

Comment: Thanks. Though there is no proxy for me, workaround in answer to this question worked: http://superuser.com/questions/403209/ssh-behind-proxy. 443 port was fine.