# Can't connect to ssh on domain network at work

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy

I have a remote Ubuntu server that I connect to via SSH on a non-standard port. I also have SSH keys set up and have `PasswordAuthentication` set to `no`. I am able to connect via PuTTY on Windows machines and `ssh` on *nix systems just fine, except from my work network. When I'm at work, I try to connect using my Windows laptop. I am able to connect just fine from this laptop at home but not at work. I thought it might be the issue described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/403209/ssh-behind-proxy) but I tried changing the ports without success. I even tried allowing traffic on the non-standard port on my Windows Firewall but no luck.

I also have `fail2ban` enabled, but my work IP is not blocked in `ufw` or `iptables`.

The interesting thing is that before I changed the port, disabled password auth, and started using keys, I was able to connect on port 22 just fine at work. But now from PuTTY it just tells me that the connection timed out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your work network might have a firewall blocking outbound SSH connections to ports other than port 22.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but when I change SSH to port 22, I still can't connect.